# MVC Portable Areas not working with Typed views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, mvccontrib, portable-areas

When using MvcContrib Portable Areas I can't get the strongly typed views to work.

I get the error message

```
'Could not load typeSystem.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<blah>
```

I've tried with built in types to check if it's an error with my type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also ran into this problem.  Consuming applications need to have the following configuration in their `web.config`

```
<pages 
     pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" 
     pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" 
     userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"> 
       <controls> 
            <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" /> 
       </controls> 
</pages>
```

I found you actually need these settings in a `web.config` within your PortableArea's project.  Without these settings, your PortableArea won't be able to resolve `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<>` and causes all sorts of crazy things to happen in the IDE.  The first thing that tipped me off was that I had no intellisense for `<%= Html`.  Then, I ran my consuming project and got a yellow screen of death:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/55542d2c51.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/55542d2c51.png)

Found the answer to this problem on [Ben Hall's blog](http://blog.benhall.me.uk/2009/01/aspnet-mvc-rc1-removing-code-behind.html).  Hope that helps.